# Allow line breaks in highlighted text

Tags: line-breaking, highlighting

When I highlight a bit of text using \colorbox, it prevents line breaking.  How does one give tex permission to break lines?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
\colorbox{yellow}{Stop playing with latex and start writing your article!}
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm sure the gut reaction will be to tell me to use such-and-such other method which already permits line-breaking.  By all means!  But resist the urge to do so while *not* answering my question :)

Comment: `\colorbox` works like `\mbox` and prevents breaking that is really deep in its nature and not really changeable, soul or ulem packages define highlighting possibilities

Comment: [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94965/wrapping-inline-long-lines-and-adding-background-color)

Comment: I see, ok, I appreciate that this is the dedicated purpose of \colorbox!

Comment: another [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85116/listing-with-background-color-not-line-breaking-correctly)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking

Comment: Why don't simply use `\hl` command from [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package?

Comment: @karlkoeller Indeed, and thanks!  But to answer your question, the reason for my question was to understand how TeX thinks about newlines which I find baffling, this providing a simple concrete case. I thought maybe there is a simple command that permits line breaking.  Based on David's answer, I sense this is a deep question which deserves a comprehensive reading of intro material...