# How to highlight few sentences in a paragraph?

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I would like to get a simple result, as the following

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Does [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart) or [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/8323 seems nice! Thanks

Comment: Also here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking

Comment: if the font is monotype as your image suggest, then perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85259/4686 is related.

Comment: also related this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94965/wrapping-inline-long-lines-and-adding-background-color

Comment: No, the font is not monotype :)

Comment: You could try `soul` package as in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5980/4686

Comment: `soul` seems to be the best and easiest solution!

Comment: `soul` seems to be not enough robust...