# make soul highlight span lines

Tags: color, line-spacing, highlighting, soul, annotations

The `\hl` command from the `soul` package highlights spans of text with a backround color when `color` is loaded. When used on longer spans of text, some inter-line spacing remains uncolored, which is rather unpleasant to my eye.

```
\documentclass[a8paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}
  This is some text \hl{of that some part should be highlighted. This part spans multiple lines}, which is easy on a8paper.
\end{document}
```

[image: current outcome]

I already tried to tinker with `\setul`, but increasing the height and depth there just enlarges the line height, leaving unchanged the spacing in between.

Is there a way to have the result look like this?

[image: sought result]

Answers do not have to be restricted to the package. (Meaning `soul`-less answers  are also welcome. ;)

Answer (score 7):

A non-soul approach can be found in [wrapping inline long lines and adding background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94965/wrapping-inline-long-lines-and-adding-background-color)

And see also [Listing with background color not line breaking correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85116/listing-with-background-color-not-line-breaking-correctly)

But it is impossible to re-create with a few macros all the job done by [soul](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul).(*) Here is a customization of `soul`'s highlighting driver which seems to obtain what is required:

(*) besides the solutions linked to above seem to be using only monotype font.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\sethlcolor{red}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{\dp\strutbox}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax}%
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[textwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}\raggedcolumns
  This is some text \hl{of that some part should be highlighted. This part
    spans multiple lines}, which is easy on a8paper.
\columnbreak

  This is some text {of that some part should be highlighted. This part
    spans multiple lines}, which is easy on a8paper.
\columnbreak

  This is some text \hl{of that some part should be highlighted. This part
    spans multiple lines}, which is easy on a8paper.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: soul highlighting]