# Customizing highlighting from soul

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, highlighting, soul

I am using the following customization from [make soul highlight span lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282386/make-soul-highlight-span-lines) for the `\hl` from `soul` to get rid of the gaps between the highlighted zones:

```
\documentclass[a8paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\sethlcolor{LightBlue}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
\setul{\dp\strutbox}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax}
\let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
\SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is some \hl{highlighted text with a formula $q=\frac{p}{r}$. 
Notice how nicely it is highlighted.} 

Writting something more fancy, say, \hl{$|a|=\inf_{\overline{f}=a}|f|$, 
gives an obvious gap problem.}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

However, if there are symbols that extend below/above too much, the `\hl` does not fully highlight the gap, as the above example shows. I tried to fiddle with the `\setul` part but nothing seems to give a good result. I also tried to `\smash` the inf construction, but then the line below just overlaps with the one above.

What would be the right setup to highlight that gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some more to the depth (and the thickness), also setting `\lineskip` to zero. Note that this changes the interline space, but there's no way that I know for convincing `soul` and `\hl` to cover something that exceeds the stated depth for the underline (the background color is realized as underlining with a very thick rule).

```
\documentclass[a8paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\sethlcolor{LightBlue}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
\setul{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+2pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox+2pt\relax}
\let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
\SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}

This is some \hl{highlighted text with a formula $q=\frac{p}{r}$.
Notice how nicely it is highlighted.}

Writting something more fancy, say, \hl{$|a|=\inf_{\overline{f}=a}|f|$,
gives an obvious gap problem.}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\hl` in your final document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "Don't use `\hl` in your final document" ? Is there a better method to do this kind of highlighting without using `soul`?